# How test if data fit a 0/1 line?

Tags: r, regression

I am interested in testing, in R, whether a plot fits the line with intercept = 0, slope = 1.

To be concrete, you can imagine the data are generated as follows:

```
x = runif(100)
y = runif(100)
```

Visually, the plot is likely to be close to the line described above. But I want a statistical test either providing a thumbs up or down (fits, doesn't fit) and/or that specifies the goodness of fit.

As to goodness of fit I am of course aware of the correlation coefficient, but that doesn't care about the intercept or slope. For example,

```
cor(x, y) == cor(100 + x, 10*y)
```

Thanks.

Comment: The concordance correlation coefficient (Lin, 1989) evaluates the degree to which pairs of observations fall on the 45° line through the origin. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordance_correlation_coefficient

Comment: The example you give has totally independent $x$ and $y$ variables, meaning that the scatterplot will not hug $y=x$. This makes me wonder what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can apply a test for dependence of $x$ and $y$ to independent $x$ and $y$, though it would of course be more useful to test on data that satisfy and violate the hypothesis being tested.

Comment: There are a great many possible solutions depending on how you model the data. For instance, are you assuming that both the $x$ and $y$ variables have important random components? And how do you wish to measure the goodness of fit between a set of points and a line? There are a great many choices. We recognize you might not be able to articulate your needs mathematically, but if you could explain the underlying real-world problem you're trying to solve, it would give us important clues for identifying good solutions.

Comment: BTW, perhaps the simplest and most natural approach to testing is to compare the $x-y$ values to $0$ (and there are many ways to do that, depending on your assumptions), but it would be unwise to propose doing that without knowing more.

Comment: How would you feel about constructing a confidence interval for (each of) the intercept and slope?  And  then consider if the confidence interval  for e.g. the slope contains 1.

Answer (score 3):

Fit as a null model the 0 degree of freedom linear regression model

`fit0 <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(x)`.

which has intercept and slope constrained to be 0 and 1 exactly. Consider the two-parameter alternative

`fit2 <- lm(y ~ x)`

to determine whether the squared errors in the alternate fit provide a statistically significant better fit to the data.

the `lmtest` package provides a number of tests. The likelihood ratio test is preferred by many when testing nested models.

`lrtest(fit2, fit0)`

which compares the log likelihood ratio to a two-degree of freedom chi-squared distribution.

Comment: A simpler solution (as suggested in one of my comments to the question) is to fit the model `y-x ~ 1+x` and test both its coefficients simultaneously with zeros (the default procedure).

Comment: @whuber agreed, and just to comment: these should lead to exactly the same results.