# What statistical test to determine if a fit line is different from a slope of 1?

Tags: regression

I am using R for statistical analysis. I think of a linear regression or lm() function, in simplistic terms, as telling me if the slope of a fit line is different from zero. However, in the data I am analyzing, I am trying to tell if the fit line is different from a slope of 1 instead.

In an attempt, I did some basic geometry to rotate my data so that the slope of 1 turned into a slope of zero. Then, I did a lm() to statically test if the slope is different than zero, but I think this is probably incorrect.

```
x1= cos(45*pi/180)*FC$variable1 + sin(45*pi/180)*FC$variable2
y1= -sin(45*pi/180)*FC$variable1 + cos(45*pi/180)*FC$variable2
ggplotRegression(lm(y1 ~ x1)) + xlim(-40,40) + ylim(-40,40) + geom_abline(slope=0)
summary(lm(y1 ~ x1)) 
# interpretation was that if significant then the original slope is different from 1.
```

I found this post. [How test if data fit a 0/1 line?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448868/how-test-if-data-fit-a-0-1-line/532575#532575)
So I tested it out

```
# reproducible example
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2)
y <- x/4
y2 <- x/1.01
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x, y))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=1, size=0.5) + xlim(-3,3) + ylim(-3,3)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(x, y2))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y2)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(slope=1, size=0.5) + xlim(-3,3) + ylim(-3,3)

# very obviously different from slope = 1
fit0 <- lm(y ~ 0 + offset(x))
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x)
lrtest(fit2, fit0)

# very similar
fit0 <- lm(y2 ~ 0 + offset(x))
fit2 <- lm(y2 ~ x)
lrtest(fit2, fit0)
```

Both lines are very significantly different from the slope=1 line using the likelihood ratio test (lrtest), even though the line of x and y2 is super similar to a slope=1 line.

Questions:

1. Is that the right interpretation that if the lrtest is significant then the slope of the line is different from 1 (or whatever the other fit line is in the lrtest).
2. Is there some metric that can indicate that y2 line (x/1.01) is more similar to the slope = 1 line than the y (x/4) line is?
3. Will real-life data that has error make the y2 fit less significant?

Comment: Fit the model `y-x ~ x` and test the slope for zero, as usual.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448868 for essentially the same question. Question (2) looks subjective: how do *you* wish to measure "more similar" slopes?  It's unclear what your question (3) is trying to ask: what distinctions are you implying with "real-life data" and "less significant"?

Comment: If you look at the 2 lines in the example they are clearly different from one another and one is much closer to a slope=1 than the other. 

In my manuscript, I stated the slopes of my lines but the reviewers want more formal testing of the various slopes. What I am trying to tell is if a line with a slope of say 0.74 is statistically different from a perfect fit line of slope = 1. What about it the slope is 0.89 or 0.9 or 0.95? Which lines are statistically different from a line with slope of 1 given the "real-life" error in the data. Real-life biological data is never a perfect line.

Comment: To give more context of the data maybe that will help too. I have gene expression data and x is t-statistic values for one group and y is t-statistic values for a second group. If both groups have the same response on average then the slope of the t-statistic plot will be 1. But my slopes are less than one for certain conditions and I want to test that observation statistically.